# Copy and paste rows with HSSF (Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert a row between two rows in an existing excel with HSSF (Apache POI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785724/how-to-insert-a-row-between-two-rows-in-an-existing-excel-with-hssf-apache-poi)

How can I copy the values and all the formatting of a row using HSSF. Using the MS Excel or other Spread Sheet application it is easy as copy and paste. But now I'm having problem copying a row with HSSF in Java.

My scenario right now, is I'm on the Cell:A46 and it is the last row of the table, but I still have many data to populate on the cell. I cannot simply just create a row and it cells, because I need also the formatting. And it may also break some of the formulas, because I use an excel  template which have formatting after Cell:A46.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a similar post that have an answer which solve this problem.

For the answer, just take a look on my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785724/how-to-insert-a-row-between-two-rows-in-an-existing-excel-with-hssf-apache-poi)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you not iterate trough the cells, and creating a new cell on the new row and copy the layout information from the "old" one?

---

BTW: If you have to do with may style information, then have a look at [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/index.html). It is based on POI and an be used (for example) to populate Excel files, from Excel-file based templates

Comment: Creating new cells is my last option. The reason why I need to copy and paste, is for future modification in the template. So I will not have a problem even the the templates for that row is change. And for now I cannot jump to JXLS, because I'm just adding new reports with the current application. As of now I'm creating a rows and its format as an interim solution. And yes I do iterating the cells and the rows is in the loop as I populate the rows. Anyway Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: JXLS saved my days .... thanks @Ralph for your suggestion!